# How can I Locally save data from a remote iPython notebook?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I am asking a question already asked but with no solution.

I'm using an ipython notebook that is running on a remote server. I want to save data from the notebook locally.

Currently I'm saving the data as a .csv file on the remote server and then move it over to my local machine via scp. Is there a more elegant way directly from the notebook?

Comment: You could mount an S3 bucket to your server and local computer and place the notebook there - and it will be accessable from both computers.

Comment: Clearly that is an option that works for all file types. Is there something else for notebook? I don't want to use S3 bucket.

Comment: You can probably make a link in the notebook to download the file over HTTP (try `IPython.display.FileLink`).

Comment: can you expound a bit more on `FileLink`? I tried it and it still looks like pointing to a remote location (it looks for `~` within the folder where the notebook is running)

Comment: Is there a solution now? I am looking for the same.